# objects.filter() and Foreign Key NULL

Tags: python, django, null, foreign-keys

I've written a complex search form in Django.

Here is my example model:

```
class student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   school = models.ForeignKey('school', null=True, blank=True)
class school(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So student uses a FK for school. It should be optional, so `null=True` and `blank=True` is used. If I want search for students with a specific school name I use a form with HTML code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="school_name"/>
```

And I do query the database like this (example):

```
def search(request):
 results = student.objects.filter(
    name__icontains=request.POST.get('student_name',''),
    school__name__icontains=request.POST.get('school_name','')
     )
```

Problem is: 
If I leave the search form empty, it should display all students, because no filter is applied. Thats works, if every student has set a school.
If a student has no school set, it's value in MySQL is 'NULL'. I assume they could not be found, because an empty string is not NULL. But how can I avoid that? Do I have to write an if-statement before every filter expression? We talk about 50-100 fields to filter for!

I'd be thankful for every hint to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
query = {
    'name__icontains': request.POST.get('student_name',''),
}
school_name = request.POST.get('school_name', None)
if school_name is not None:
    query['school__name__icontains'] = school_name
results = student.objects.filter(**query)
```

And similarly for the other fields. This would mean one if statement for each field. You can even do this dynamically as the keys in `query` are just strings. That means you can compute them as well and add them to `query` when needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Simeon.
I'm found a similar solution for this here:
[link]http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/04/dynamic-django-queries-with-kwargs/

Yes, that is working. But it is a lot of work, so I was hoping for something easy :-)

Comment: Also, just wanted to mention that QuerySet objects can be chained. So another alternative to write this is to say: `results = student.objects.filter(FOO)` then test something and say: `results = results.filter(BAR)`. It helps a lot when all of your conditional bits may not all be filters... some could result in a limit, or other query methods.